# Content Security Filter in Tomcat 9

Tags: filter, jar, tomcat9

I created a Content Security Filter class as suggested by some response in the web and compiled it and jarred it and put it in the Tomcat/lib folder (windows). However i am getting the following two errors -

org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.CSPFilter

Am I not jarring it properly. I am using the following package stmt -
package org.apache.catalina.filters;

The web.xml tag used is

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CSPFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CSPFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CSPFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```